# Python: How to remove subString from list of elements and each elements entry should be one time?

Tags: python, string, list

1) How to remove sub-string from the python list elements. I found number of threads from this forum but didn't get proper hint specific to my case.

2) How to remove common dates and keep only one entry of each date among multiple entries having same data in below code.

```
['2010-01-29 07:30:02', '2010-01-29 07:55:04', '2014-02-05 08:51:39', '2014-05-23 01:29:06', 
'2014-05-23 01:29:46', '2014-05-23 01:39:25', '2014-05-24 01:56:42', '2014-05-27 06:55:58', 
'2014-05-27 07:10:48', '2014-05-31 02:04:58', '2014-06-10 07:41:12', '2014-06-11 09:56:48', 
'2014-06-11 10:28:52',]
```

Expected output

```
['2010-01-2', '2014-02-05', '2014-05-23', '2014-05-24', '2014-05-27', '2014-05-31', 
'2014-06-10', '2014-06-11']
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `split()[0]` to get only the date for each entry, [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) to remove dupliactes, [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) to make a list from the set, finally [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) to sort the list.:

```
sorted(list(set(x.split()[0] for x in l)))
```

Result:

```
['2010-01-29',
 '2014-02-05',
 '2014-05-23',
 '2014-05-24',
 '2014-05-27',
 '2014-05-31',
 '2014-06-10',
 '2014-06-11']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:  `sorted(list(set(i.split()[0] for i in l)))`

Sample run:

```
>>> l=['2010-01-29 07:30:02', '2010-01-29 07:55:04', '2014-02-05 08:51:39', '2014-05-23 01:29:06', 
... '2014-05-23 01:29:46', '2014-05-23 01:39:25', '2014-05-24 01:56:42', '2014-05-27 06:55:58', 
... '2014-05-27 07:10:48', '2014-05-31 02:04:58', '2014-06-10 07:41:12', '2014-06-11 09:56:48', 
... '2014-06-11 10:28:52']
>>> l
['2010-01-29 07:30:02', '2010-01-29 07:55:04', '2014-02-05 08:51:39', '2014-05-23 01:29:06', '2014-05-23 01:29:46', '2014-05-23 01:39:25', '2014-05-24 01:56:42', '2014-05-27 06:55:58', '2014-05-27 07:10:48', '2014-05-31 02:04:58', '2014-06-10 07:41:12', '2014-06-11 09:56:48', '2014-06-11 10:28:52']
>>> sorted(list(set(i.split()[0] for i in l)))
['2010-01-29', '2014-02-05', '2014-05-23', '2014-05-24', '2014-05-27', '2014-05-31', '2014-06-10', '2014-06-11']
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks: It works But the issue in your solution is change the elements in different orders. How to have output in same order of source list?

Comment: What is the input order, is it sorted ascending by date?

Comment: Yes! same sequence as in source list (here list l). bdw thanks for input.

Answer (score 0):

Using collections.Counter

```
>>> my_list = ['2010-01-29 07:30:02', '2010-01-29 07:55:04', '2014-02-05 08:51:39', '2014-05-23 01:29:06',
... '2014-05-23 01:29:46', '2014-05-23 01:39:25', '2014-05-24 01:56:42', '2014-05-27 06:55:58',
... '2014-05-27 07:10:48', '2014-05-31 02:04:58', '2014-06-10 07:41:12', '2014-06-11 09:56:48',
... '2014-06-11 10:28:52',]
>>> my_counter = collections.Counter(x.split()[0] for x in my_list)
>>> my_counter
Counter({'2014-05-23': 3, '2014-06-11': 2, '2014-05-27': 2, '2010-01-29': 2, '2014-05-31': 1, '2014-06-10': 1, '2014-05-24': 1, '2014-02-05': 1})
>>> my_counter.keys()
['2014-05-31', '2014-06-10', '2014-06-11', '2014-05-24', '2014-05-27', '2010-01-29', '2014-05-23', '2014-02-05']
```

Using `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> result = [x for x,y in itertools.groupby(sorted(x.split()[0] for x in my_list))]
>>> result
['2010-01-29', '2014-02-05', '2014-05-23', '2014-05-24', '2014-05-27', '2014-05-31', '2014-06-10', '2014-06-11']
```